# LINQ to SQL bug? Sequence contains more than one element

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm using the following query:

```
            return (
                from c in dataContext.Contacts
                where c.ContactID == contactID
                select c
            ).SingleOrDefault();
```

In this case, by stepping through, "contactID" equals "6646".  "c.ContactID" is the primary key field on the "Contact" table in SQL Server 2008 database.  I have run a simple select query in SSMS

```
select * from contact where contactid = 6646
```

I get one result.  But the LINQ to SQL query throws the "Sequence contains more than one element" error.

I have double and triple checked connection strings and primary key columns definitions.  It's not clear to me how this can be happening.

Comment: This looks strange, Check the query using SQL Server Profiler to see what *actually* is getting executed on the server. Later check your mapping and make sure that `ContactID` is mapped to an actual Primary Key.

Comment: Can you show the signature of the method (where the method is declared, including the return type and parameters)?

Comment: Do you have tables named Contact and Contacts (plural)?  Is it possible that you are querying different tables with your Linq to SQL and SQL?

Comment: Okay, that helped Habib.  It's an odd duck of a problem.  I am using Load Options to load related objects, one of which is defined to be one-to-one, however, there exist two in the database (for some reason).  LINQ to SQL must also throw this error when prefetching 1-1 related objects.

Answer (score 1):

That is an InvalidOperationException thrown by the Single method.

This method is supposed to return only one element, and your query is returning more than one, you have to check the criteria you use on your query.

It will also throw an exception if it doesn't find an element. You can use SingleOrDefault() method to return null (or default value, i.e. 0 for int) if there are no records.

If you are expecting multiple elements but just one the first one, you can use First instead of Single or FirstOrDefault.

try to debug and put a Where instead the Single so you will be able to see what are the rows that shouldn't be there

Comment: First the OP is using `SingleOrDefault`.  Second the OP is asking why it's returning multiple records when they are filtering on the primary key of the table.  Thought the recommendation to use a `Where` and inspect the results is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately came down to using LoadOptions to load related objects, one of which was defined in LINQ to SQL to be 1-1.  However, in the associated table there were two records associated.  So although the primary table the query was running against contained only one element, as expected, LINQ to SQL was using a Left Join  to load the related objects, one of which was duplicated, causing two records to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Use FirstOrDefault.

SingleOrDefault is used when you are expecting only one item, i know that in this case it wouldn't be a problem but give it a try.

Comment: Of course I would have done this, but as I specified, I was doing a search on the primary key column, so I knew there was something else going on somewhere.